# Meteor: how do I return data from fields in a specific object?

Tags: json, mongodb, meteor, find, mongodb-query

This should be a fairly simple one.

`myobject` has various properties, `_id, name, createdBy, date` etc

In my find query I want to only return specific fields from within myObject.  So for example, what would I need to do to modify the find query below so that only `name` was returned?

```
myCollection.find({createdBy: someId}, {fields: {myObject: 1}}).fetch();
```

Currently this will return everything in `myObject` which it should do, I just want one field within `myObject` returned.

Comment: I'm unclear if you are looking for an array of names or an array of objects with only the `myObject.name` field set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it within the query:

> myCollection.find({createdBy: someId}, {fields: {'myObject.name':
>   1}}).fetch();

Note the quotes around

> 'myObject.name'

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume we are talking about posts, and a post document looks like this:

```js
{
  _id: 'abc123',
  title: 'All about meteor',
  author: {
    firstName: 'David',
    lastName: 'Weldon'
  }
}
```

You can then extract all of the last names from all of the authors with this:

```js
var lastNames = Posts.find().map(function(post) {
  return post.author.lastName;
});
```

Modify the selector and options as needed for your collection. Using `fields` in this case may be a small optimization if you are running this on the server and fetching the data directly from the DB.